# Multiple UITableView in a single ViewController with custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift

1. I implemented 2 TableViews in a single ViewController
2. One TableView with a custom cell called TreeViewCell. Another with Basic UITableViewCell (both cell draw in the storyboard with its own TableView)

Ask: I have a problem when returning its own cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to `return cell` within the `if { } else { }` statement directly. and delete `cell: UITableViewCell` you cast it twice actually this is not usefull. Note: and try to paste your code, not images ;)

Comment: but what should be the default value of cell in else statement?

Comment: `cell = UItableViewCell()` simply. You will never come there anyway

Comment: Still can not. This is wierd

Comment: You just pasted the link not the picture. Anyway try to edit your post and past your actual code not screenshoots

Comment: Still asked me to return UITableViewCell even though I did this if {... } else { return UITableViewCell() }

Comment: In my another project, I did 2 tableviews in a single ViewController but both tableview with basic cell and That works fine, Having this problem with custom UITableViewCell. UNABLE TO CAST custom UITableViewCell

Comment: Oh my god man! I forgot to put return in each if/ if else statement. Thanks man for your help. Its works. You put it as an answer I will accept!

Comment: Ép kiểu kiểu đó không được, cell vẫn chỉ là UITableViewCell thôi, ko phải TreeViewCell, nên ko có phương thức setNodeData đâu. Return trong từng block if đi, let cell:TreeNodeData = ....

Comment: ok @NguyenHoan understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply return your `cell` in your if statement like so :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // get rid of the `var cell: UITableViewCell!`

    if tableView == tableViewUser {
        cell = tableViewUser.dequeuReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! TreeViewCell 
        cell.setNodeData(node: self.displayArray[indexPath.row])
        return cell 
    }

    if tableView == tableViewSearch {
        cell = tableViewUser.dequeuReusableCell(withIdentifier: "searchCell", for: indexPath) 
        cell.textLabel.text = "123456"
        return cell 
    }

    return UITableViewCell() // dont worry, you will never go there
}
```

---

Also uncomment the `register` part on your `tableViewUser` `didSet`

Comment: No man, return UITableViewCell() have to be in else { } statement, if not that code will always execute. Please edit your answer!

Comment: dont worry it will sork fine too. When it enters one of the `if { }` it will reach the `return cell` statement and end the function straight away. This is perfectly equivalent, just less lines of code. Try it you will see